# Special characters with read.csv loading as full stops when header = TRUE

Tags: r, csv

I have a `\t` delimited `.csv` file with names of columns in the first row and some `,` decimal sign numbers in others. I am trying to read it with `read.csv()` command like so:

```
x = read.csv("Export.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ",")
```

in the input (file `Export.csv`) I have for example

```
"$\{,}_"
45,2
```

which gives me

```
<header>X....._</header>
45.2
```

I had expected it would interpret quoted values as strings and numbers as numbers.

It correctly interprets `45,2` as a number but messes up all special characters except underscore.

I thought it's an encoding issue so I tried few different encoding options with the same result.

Moreover if I change `header` parameter to `TRUE` I get everything displayed correctly, however all data are then interpreted as strings and (as expected) the first row is not header.

How can I load special characters to header in these circumstances?

Issue on: RStudio Version 0.98.501, R Version 3.0.2 x64, OS: Win 7 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements of one column of a `data.frame` must all have the same type. So, when you try to read in a column, it has to guess which one you want. In your second example, it reads in the first line as the header, and then guesses that the column is a numeric. It then mangles the name because `check.names` is set to `TRUE`, and your header name isn't a "valid" name (it *might* cause problems), so it tries to fix it.

In your first example, it reads in the first line, guesses that it is a character (because it isn't a number) and then the whole column becomes a character.

If you want to read in this column, with `$\{,}_` as the header name, you can do:

```
read.table(
textConnection('\"$\\{,}_\"
45,2'),header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,dec=',')
```

If you want to read this data in, and convert the elements to a `numeric` or a `character`, you'll have to read it in as a character, and then convert it yourself, placing the elements in a list.